# Want to change colour of Xcode highlighted files in Project Navigator

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a rather simple question. For some reason, I have discovered that when I highlight a file in Xcode in the Project Navigator, the highlighted file is white, instead of dark black.  Is there a way for me to change this?

Here is an example of what is happening:

[image]

As you can see, the file that is selected is highlighted as white, and I want it to be black as it always used to be.  Is this possible?

Comment: It's a common Xcode issue. Somehow it doesn't draw selection background.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This Is a common Xcode problem.

You can easily fix it when it happens by **pressing Cmd+0 two times** (one to hide the Navigator and one to show it again).

Comment: Thanks very much for sharing this!

Answer (score 0):

Turn off reduce transparency can fix it! It's works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  How would I do this in Xcode?

Comment: Can't do it in Xcode. Open `System Preference` -> `Accessibility` -> `Display`

Answer (score 0):

Go to > System Preference > Accessibility > Display

Check > Reduce transparency

By Default, its already turned off. You just need to turn it ON and back to OFF. It works.

Answer (score 0):

System Preference -> Accessibility -> Display

Check > Reduce transparency

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using multiple tabs. I just closed all the tabs leaving only one opened. It's a very dangerous bug, it reverted my info.plist file to an older version.